# Printing list into fixed width strings in Python

Tags: python, string

With the following list"

```
In [3]: entr = [ 'ATOM', '1', 'P', 'C', 'B', '3', '42.564', '-34.232', '-7.330', '1.00', '105.08', 'P' ]
```

I'd like to create a string with fixed width using %. But why this failed?
Both lines contain 12 entries.

```
In [4]: buf = "%-6s%5d  %-4s%3s %1s%4d    %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f          %2s\n" % entr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6c71c289664e> in <module>()
----> 1 buf = "%-6s%5d  %-4s%3s %1s%4d    %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%6.2f%6.2f          %2s\n" % entr

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: use the new format. Ex: `"{0:010d}".format(1)`, where `10` is the width and `0` the filling value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should give a `tuple` to format operator `%`

```
"..." % tuple(entr)
```

Second, you should use `%d` for numbers, not strings! So, you need to cast this variables to `number`. Here is the short example;

```
"...%s ... %d ... %f " %(entr[1], float(entr[2]), float(entr))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think you could use this:

```
entr = [ 'ATOM', '1', 'P', 'C', 'B', '3', '42.564', '-34.232', '-7.330', '1.00', '105.08', 'P' ]
buf = "{}-6s{}5d  {}-4s{}3s {}1s{}4d    {}8.3f{}8.3f{}8.3f{}6.2f{}6.2f          {}2s\n".format(*entr)
print buf
```

Is that good?

Answer (score 1):

1) The `%`operator expect a `tuple`, you give a `list`.

2) All item in your list are strings, In you format, you use decimal and float specifier. You should cast the item in your list to the proper type.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset fields are all strings, you can notuse number formating in them. They have to be convertet to number type, also to use the %-formatting the argument has to be a tuple, not a list.

```
entr = ('ATOM', 1, 'P', 'C', 'B', 3, 42.564, -34.232, -7.330, 1.00, 105.08, 'P')
```

Answer (score 1):

With the .format operator you can do:

```
entr = [ 'ATOM', '1', 'P', 'C', 'B', '3', '42.564', '-34.232', '-7.330', '1.00', '105.08', 'P' ]

print(['{0: <6}'.format(str(x)) for x in entr])
['ATOM  ', '1     ', 'P     ', 'C     ', 'B     ', '3     ', '42.564', '-34.232', '-7.330', '1.00  ', '105.08', 'P     ']
```